# why validator isn't defined in Flutter?

Tags: validation

```
why does this problem occur in Flutter?
```

The named parameter 'validator' isn't defined.

I did form and form key but it is still wrong.

I erased the rest for not being long.

`This problem`

```
   TextField(
                  
                   validator : (value){
                    if(value.isempty){
                      return 'Email must not be empty';
                    }
                    return null;
                  }
                ),
```

Comment: `TextField` does not have a `validator`. Check out `TextFormField`, which does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `TextFormField` instead of `TextField` because `TextField` doesn't use and functionality of `Form` and `validator` is functionality of `Form`.

Refer this [3 errors in make components in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73289520/3-errors-in-make-components-in-flutter) for more details.