# 3 errors in make components in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, null-safety

I have 3 errors
I tried all possible solutions
look at this

```
Widget defaultFormField ({
  @required TextEditingController? controller,
  @required TextInputType? keyboardType,
  @required IconData? prefix,
  @required String? label,
  VoidCallback? onChange,
  @required VoidCallback? validate,

}) => TextFormField(
    style: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
    cursorHeight: 25.0,
    cursorColor: Colors.amber,
    controller: controller,
    keyboardType: keyboardType,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
      labelText: label,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.amber
        ),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.amber,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    onChanged: onChange,
    validator : validate,
);
```

these are problems

> Invalid constant value.

> The argument type 'void Function()?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)?'.

> The argument type 'void Function()?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)?'.

Comment: in which line you are getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove `const` from this line `decoration: const InputDecoration(` .
2. `required Function? onChange`,
3. `required Function? validator`,

use `onChanged` like this

```
 onChanged: (value) {
         return onChanged != null ? onChanged(value) : null;
  },
```

use `validator` like this

```
validator: (value) {
            return validator != null ? validator(value) : null;
          },
```

try above code it can solve your error.
and remove @ from `required`.

Comment: It is ok to have `const` on `InputDecoration`

Comment: I don't think so because he/she is using label property inside InputDecoration

Comment: my mistake, I removed from test case

Comment: That's okay @YeasinSheikh

Comment: all problems have solved  Really Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`onChanged` provide string on callback, do it like

```dart
Function(String)? onChange,
```

Also for `validator` it can be

```dart
 required Function(String?) validate,

validator : (value) =>  validate(value),
```

`defaultFormField` method

```dart
 Widget defaultFormField({
    required TextEditingController? controller,
    required TextInputType? keyboardType,
    required IconData? prefix,
    required String? label,
    Function(String)? onChange,
    required Function(String?) validate,
  }) =>
      TextFormField(
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.amber,
        ),
        cursorHeight: 25.0,
        cursorColor: Colors.amber,
        controller: controller,
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
          labelText: label,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.amber),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onChanged: onChange,
        validator: (value) => validate(value),
      );
```

Comment: Also no need to use `@` , and added validated